# Create Fixed Size xz archive

Tags: 7-zip, xz

I want to create an xz archive with exact size 8MB, I use 7z to create archive but the size is less than 8MB I know xz support padding to increase size
but I dont know which tools suppurt this feature or 7z support it or not

Comment: Why not use the XZ utilities directly if you do know they support it?

Comment: It is one of xz benefit they wrote in xz document, I checked xz utils but i didn't find any args to set padding size @Seth

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the documentation of XZ [1](https://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=history;f=src/xz/xz.1;hb=d0e58b3a51e8e616f3dc26ec7b7e4aa0fa6991ad):

> Concatenation and padding with .xz files
>      It is possible to concatenate .xz files as is.  xz will decompress such
>      files as if they were a single .xz file.
>
> It  is  possible  to  insert  padding between the concatenated parts or
>      after the last part.  The padding must consist of null  bytes  and  the
>      size of the padding must be a multiple of four bytes.  This can be use-
>      ful e.g. if the .xz file is stored on a medium that measures file sizes
>      in 512-byte blocks.
>
> Concatenation  and  padding  are  not  allowed  with .lzma files or raw
>     streams.

In short you will have to do the padding on your own. The header and block padding [2](https://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=history;f=doc/xz-file-format.txt;h=4ed665060183375b8a1fb74384d01636042b1bcf;hb=refs/heads/master) are not something you will be able to influence. You will have to use an appropiate tool to generate null bytes in multiples of four.

Comment: I know that ,but I dont know how to add padding is it possible to make an example how to add padding to header and fix crc

Comment: If you know that why would you not add that to your question? For example you could use `dd` and `cat`. In addition you're looking at such a corner case that I'm really wondering why you'd bother with such a cumbersome process. There might be a way easier option available.